# Can this work - Objective-C UI supplied by a Java back-end packaged into one Mac Desktop App?

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, user-interface

Professionally I am a back-end Java developer, but recently I've been interested in writing a desktop application for Mac, and have started to learn Objective-C as a result. My problem is that the more I delve into the complexities of Objective-C, the more I wish I was just writing my application in Java, especially to make use of the myriad of frameworks etc. that Java has to offer.

So my question is this: can anyone give me a (convincing!) reason not to develop my new projects back-end in Java, and the UI in Objective-C? Basically, I'm asking someone to shoot me out of the water, tell me I'm a fool for even considering it!

What are the disadvantages to this approach? Performance I imagine will be paramount, but in my experience with Java, the back-end tends to approach native code performance (when written well). Could this approach even work? Perhaps with some fancy messaging framework (json?) pumping data between the Java and Objective-C sides?

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large amount of existing Java code, then this is a feasible plan. Communicating between the UI and the "back-end" can be done using the [Java Native Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2147/_index.html) to box objects/method calls back and forth, rather than having to design and implement a network protocol.

However, keep in mind that Java is not shipped with the latest versions of Mac OS X (users will be prompted to download and install it), and apps that include Java components will not be accepted on the Mac App Store.

Comment: I'd like to keep things as separate as possible if I was to adopt my plan, so JNI probably wouldn't work. Long term I'd like to write it all in Obj-C, but to kick-start the dev on this it'd be convenient for me to use what I'm comfortable with.

But great point re: Java not shipping with OS X, and it not being acceptable on the App Store - I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

This approach cam work with the help of Sockets. Your objective-c programs will send request in JSON or whatsoever format to backend java on particular socket and keep listening on particular socket, what java program will do is listen on socket shared get that request and create required response and send back to listening socket. I will not be able to give any source code for this until and unless I understand your requirement in detail.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Issue with JNI in this case is , you can call C or C++ code from java, but I am not sure it is that much easy to call reverse. Here, requirement is Objective-C user interface needs to call backend Java program. I am also curious this can be done using JNI?

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

You can decide for it if you have to supply many different devices like iphone, tablets, android, windows phone, etc. It'd be a such good idea once you wouldn't have to copy and paste the same code many times. The same could be used on website.

This approach also can be done if you have a cross functional team. I mean a team to maintain the backend, another front-end for phones, another front-end for website etc.

It is more flexible approach and I prefer it. But it might be what fit better to you, if you go through backend and objective-c will take longer than everything on objective-c. On objective-c approach is good for short term but for a long term a backend that cares about the data would be the deal!